# where does the log is created by default in FAKE F#Make?

Tags: f#, msbuild, f#-fake

I am trying to build a csproj file with FAKE, following the "Getting started with FAKE - F# Make" tutorial from the FAKE website. I am trying to understand what this line is doing:

```
|> Log "AppBuild-Output: "
```

I understand that it is creating the log of the respective build. But where is this log file being created?

This is the code:

```
Target "BuildApp" (fun _ ->
!! "src/app/**/*.csproj"
|> MSBuildRelease buildDir "Build"
|> Log "AppBuild-Output: "
)
```

When I delete the last line, i.e. if i write:

```
Target "BuildApp" (fun _ ->
!! "src/app/**/*.csproj"
|> MSBuildRelease buildDir "Build"
)
```

I am getting an error, `type 'unit' doesn't match the type 'string list'`.

Comment: It's not a file. Log output goes to stdout.

Comment: Thank you .
If I dont want to log the output , then it throws an error
'' type 'unit' doesn't match the type 'string list'  "

Comment: Add `|> ignore` at the end.

Comment: adding this |> ignore  doesn't ignore the output. though it is not giving any error but output remains same .

Comment: I never said it would ignore the output.

Comment: Thanks  , But what is this doing then ?

Comment: It ignores the return value of `MSBuildRelease`.

Comment: ohhkay ...Thank You :)